# First order linear ODE solution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function

Given the following ODE

$$
2\left[1 - x - b\right]y' -2a(1-x)y + x^{a+1}=0
$$

I am trying to find a solution for $y(x)$. My approach has been to firstly rearrange the equation in the canonical form

$$
y' - \frac{a(1-x)}{1-x-b}y = - \frac{z^{a+1}}{2(1-x-b)}
$$

Then, multiply by the following integrating factor

$$
\mu(x) = \exp \left(-\int \frac{a(1-x)}{1-x-b}dx\right) = (1-x-b)^{ab}e^{-ax}
$$

This allows me to write the equation in the form

$$
\frac d{dx} \left((1-x-b)^{ab}e^{-ax} y\right) = - \frac{x^{a+1}}{2(1-x-b)} (1-x-b)^{ab}e^{-ax}
$$

It is at this point that I am not 100% sure on how to proceed. Integrating both sides, I have an integral that looks like a Gamma integral

$$
\Gamma(z) = \int^\infty_0 t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt
$$

I have the boundary condition that $y(1)=1$, so I think I can fix the integration limits between $\int^1_x$, however, I'm struggling to make the final step.

Answer (score -1):

Every first order differential equation in the form of $ay'+by+c=0$ (where $a , b, c, y$ are functions of $x$) can be written as $\frac{d}{dx}\left({\mu y}\right)=-c\mu$, so in your case,
$$\mu=(1-x-b)^{ab}e^{-ax}, b=\frac{-a(1-x)}{1-x-b}, c=\frac{x^{a+1}}{2(1-x-b)}$$

If we rearrange the statement $\frac{d}{dx}\left({\mu y}\right)=-c\mu$, we get
$$y=\frac{-\int c\mu\space dx}{\mu}$$

But, when entered in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2C2%5DPower%5Bx%2Ca%2B1%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%291-x-b%5C%2841%29%2Cab-1%5DPower%5Be%2C-ax%5D%2Cx%5D) , it says that the integral $\int c\mu\space dx$ has no solution in terms of standard mathematical functions, hence y cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Therefore, no solution of y exists.

Comment: @TShiong how did you do such a level of formatting? How did you center the y = - integral stuff...?

Comment: You need learn formatting in LaTex.

Comment: But I did learn, but still dont know how to do that. Can you recommend a good website?